# How do you switch character styles?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

I have unlocked outfits in my archives, but I still can't change character styles when I'm playing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you didn't give precision about what you are playing on (Ps3, Xbox360, PC,..).

I'll go with Ps3, when you select your character, instead of pressing (X), press (start) and you will be prompted with a style selection window. Choose what you want, and there you go.